# Tag "soul" vs. tag "souls"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

In trying to use the tag [soul](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul) recently, I found that the tag in the system is [souls](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/souls).

It seems odd to me to prefer the plural over the singular. I propose converting the tag to the singular [soul](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul).

We do have the [spirit](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirit) tag defined as "the traditional component of a person distinct from 'body' and 'mind'. Perhaps the two should be synonyms. I personally favor [soul](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul) over [spirit](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirit) as the primary tag, but it is not that important to me.

Alternatively, we have the tag [human-body](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-body), so perhaps we might prefer [human-soul](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-soul). I do not, however, because I think we have [human-body](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-body) to differentiate from various Eucharistic [body-tags](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body-tags) (though the only one we currently have is [incorruptible-body](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incorruptible-body)).

So I propose that we create the [soul](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soul) tag to replace [souls](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/souls) and give it a definition something like this:

> **soul**
>   The spirit of life within the human body. Sometimes used to refer to an immortal essence of every human. Also, sometimes used as a synonym for any living human.

I think the tag should avoid more than that because there are many different interpretations on what the soul is or even that the immortal soul exists. I am even in favor of it being just the first sentence.

Comment: There is already a [thread for tag synonym suggestions](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/229/tag-synonym-suggestions). Though this post is more involved than just suggesting a tag synonym, it might still have fit there.